# Grub not creating a boot option in UEFI Dual-Boot Win10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, bios

Before i start, this is what i have tried:
I did disable secure-boot and enabled "launch CSM" in UEFI
Boot Repair (3 kinds)
Checked Disc for Errors 
Re-partitioning
tried 5 diff Linux-based OS's Same issue.

Ok, so i really wanna learn more, that is why i need Ubuntu, but MicroSoft decides i dont deserve to know things that doesn't pertain to them. 
My issue is, after installing Ubuntu, i dont have the option to boot it in UEFI.
as if UEFI doesn't detect/register the installation, i have been using Ubuntu Live without issues. When i first Install, does it matter if i install with Ubuntu or with the Grub bootloader? I have tried both but im still not sure. I'm new to this UEFI crap and it my knowledge of BIOS isn't helping me much here.i read some other post about similar issues, but they dont seem to work for my issue. i am dual booting windows10 with Ubuntu and my EUFI is just making me salty, Help me... Plz.... i wanna know things

Comment: Good advice in Answer by Rod Smith. Also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Answer (score 0):

if you can access the windows operation system then use **Easybcd** tool.but if you are in linux machine then follow the below command.may be it will help you

```
mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub
exit
umount /mnt/dev/pts
umount /mnt/dev
umount /mnt/proc
umount /mnt/sys
umount /mnt
```

This will restore the old kali linux boot loader, however, you will have to boot into kali once the live cd is out, so as to add windows into the boot loader. Once booted, go to the terminal and do the following:

Code:

*os-prober
update-grub*

... and thats it. hope this helps. I think this will also work with windows xp,vista, and 8, but i haven't yet tested on those systems, so i can't confirm.

Comment: As I understand it, EasyBCD is still pretty useless on EFI-based computers.  My suspicion is that your commands to fix GRUB will also fail, since they're designed for a BIOS-mode GRUB install -- and if I understand the question properly, that's already working -- the issue is a mixed-mode (BIOS/UEFI) install, not a broken GRUB per se.

Answer (score 0):

> I did disable secure-boot and enabled "launch CSM"

This was almost certainly a mistake -- enabling the CSM makes it easy to create a mixed-mode installation -- Windows in EFI mode and Ubuntu in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. This is a recipe for frustration. Please read [my Web page on this subject](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) before you do anything else, since you could easily dig yourself in deeper if you don't understand what's happening.

The easiest solution is likely to be to disable the CSM and re-install Ubuntu; however, you should be careful about partitioning if you do this, since some of the automatic options will wind up creating a second Ubuntu installation side-by-side with Windows and the first Ubuntu, which of course would be a waste of disk space.

Alternatively, you can install an EFI boot loader for Linux for your current installation. This is simpler in some ways, but takes more knowledge. See [my Web page on EFI boot loaders for Linux](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/index.html) if you want to try this approach; or you can use [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to set up GRUB in a semi-automated fashion -- but the emergency disk you boot *must* be booted in EFI mode to get this to work.